# How can I view customer account actions?

Tags: customer, view

I am trying to find a way that lets me see what customers have logged in from a set period time is that possible? I checked my advanced reporting but I always get a message that says "Some pieces of your data appear to be missing
".

Answer (score 0):

you should look at the module that allows you to log in and keep track of your data model then surely you will have a field in relation to the customer table then with this field you could build a method to query the session time of the customer under study